# Do these insulation panels contain asbestos?

Tags: drywall, insulation, asbestos, fiberglass, partition

The landlord said that "it's plastic stock, left from renovation on windows" from another apartment. It doesn't look like plastic to me, but then again I don't know much (very little actually) about construction materials. If it's asbestos can it be harmful just by passing by it while breathing in?

[image]
[image]
[image: There 3 boards on over the other]

[image: s]

Comment: Even if it is asbestos (it doesn't look like it to me...) you can't be harmed "just by passing by it while breathing in" unless it is in a *friable* state (i.e. in a state where loose fibers can become airborne). It does not look to be in that state, it seems stable.

Comment: Given that this appears to be new construction materials (as you were told, but also, not looking decades old) odds are about zero it would be/contain asbestos.

Comment: Asbestos is nasty.  Aside from give anyone who looks at it cross-eyed cancer, it can seduce your girlfriend, run up your credit cards, get your Xbox account banned, crank call your ex, drink all your beer, and send hokey memes to all your email contacts.  Seriously, though, it's asbestos, not dioxin.  **And it's not even asbestos**.

Comment: @Harper, lol thanks for this one, made me laugh

Comment: @Harper, it is not anywhere as dangerous as dihydrogen monoxide ... that stuff is everywhere and if you inhale some of it, it can kill you

Comment: @Ecnerwal I see your point. It's just Russia where I live nowadays it's the world's largest producer of asbestos. I'd expect them to generally use it in new construction materials.

Comment: @Harper yah, that was funny (kinda), but see I grew up in a country where asbestos was a big no-no and even today it makes the news if it's found in school buildings and public edifices. Now I live in another country where there's little if any concern about such things. Personally, I rather be unjustifiably worried than caught by surprise.

Comment: Asbestos is a [moral panic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_panic).  What's actually true is that people who work daily for an entire career inhaling friable mineral wools, have an increased rate of lung cancer.  Operative words "daily", "for an entire career", "inhaling", and "friable".  The asbestos industry lost in court, and set up a **trust fund**. It's easy to tap that fund.  So lawyers are on a feeding frenzy to tap that fund, for 1/3 contingency fee for very little work.  Hence all the advertising and publicity and "public awareness".  Truth be told, fiberglass is bad too.

Comment: Back when I was involved in web monetization, and most keywords paid a nickel a click, one word was at the top, and I had to look it up.   "Mesothelioma" (asbestos cancer) was bid up to ***$20 a click. USD!*** It was the most valuable real estate on the entire web.  Far more than porn/gambling/pharma.  It's insane.  The lawyers **whipped the entire world into a frenzy** to reach 1/10,000 of the population.

Answer (score 1):

I would 99+% guarantee it is urethane foam . One of the raw material components is cyanide if you want to worry.

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry.... it's not asbestos. Fiberboard.

Answer (score 0):

That is rigid insulation it is not asbestos.